# How can I convert variables into a string with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to Javascript.  I'd like to store multiple string variables into one variable, then print this value.  Below is an example of how I'd like this to work:

```
var Name1 = John;
var Name2 = Doe;

var formVariables = Name1 + Name2;

alert(formVariables);
```

What I'd like to see in the alert is:  JohnDoe
But this doesn't work.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: You don't have any strings.

Comment: So new that you haven't learned the syntax to create strings? It's the same as almost every other language you're likely to have used before.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it was a beginner's mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you have

```
var Name1 = John;
```

Javascript is interpreting John as a variable not a string! To make it interpret john as a string you must wrap it in `" "` or `' '`

**Solution 1**

```
var Name1 = 'John';
var Name2 = 'Doe';

var formVariables = Name1 + Name2;

alert(formVariables);
```

**Solution 2**

```
var John = 'John';
var Doe = 'Doe';
var Name1 = John;
var Name2 = Doe;

var formVariables = Name1 + Name2;

alert(formVariables);
```

Answer (score 1):

String literals are surrounded by quotes (either single or double, so long as they match).  So it looks like you want:

```
var Name1 = "John";
var Name2 = "Doe";
```

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend a generic object:

```
var names = {
    name1 = "John",
    name2 = "Doe"
}
alert(names.name1, names.name2);
```

or an array:

```
var names = array();
names.push("John");
names.push("Doe");
var arrayLength = names.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    alert(names[i]);
}
```

if you use jQuery, it's even simpler to iterate through the array:

```
$.each(names, function(index, value){
    alert(names(value));
}
```